# How to convert average time returened from sql query to minutes

Tags: php, sql, time, duration, milliseconds

I am running the following query

```
SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(AVG(TIME_TO_SEC(Response_Time))) as avg_time
FROM    Case_report
where Reporting_Time between "'.$fromdate.'" and "'.$todate.'"
  and Police_Circle="Sadar"
```

and getting the correct result from sql as " 00:19:35.6000 "

I need to get result in total minutes Like  20

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (When it comes to date/time, many products are far from ANSI SQL compliant.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this part of your SQL, you convert the total seconds into a time, which is why you get your output as time:

```
SEC_TO_TIME(AVG(TIME_TO_SEC(Response_Time)))
```

Instead of converting the result back to a time, just divide the seconds by 60 and round the number to get the total minutes:

```
ROUND(AVG(TIME_TO_SEC(Response_Time)) / 60)
```

In your original SQL statement:

```
SELECT  ROUND(AVG(TIME_TO_SEC(Response_Time)) / 60) AS avg_time
  FROM  Case_report
  where Reporting_Time between "'.$fromdate.'" and "'.$todate.'"
        and Police_Circle="Sadar"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot , worked perfectly fine as i needed , bundle of thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple function in PHP like:

```
function getMinutes($timestring){

    $tmp = explode(':',str_replace('.','',$timestring)); 
    $minutes = (int)$tmp[0] * 60 + ceil($tmp[1].'.'.$tmp[2]);

    return $minutes;
}

$s  = '00:19:35.6000'; 
$s2 = '01:19:35.6000'; 

echo getMinutes($s);
echo PHP_EOL;
echo getMinutes($s2);
```

Output:

```
20
80
```

**[Demo](https://3v4l.org/ldqQZ)**